# Different result in IDE and command line, Boolean seems to change value

Tags: python, command-line, boolean, spyder, argparse

I have a Python 3 program in which I have a strange behavior that I reduced to the very basic MWE below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# basic_test.py
import argparse

def fun(arg1):
    print("arg1 value right before test: ", arg1)
    if arg1:
        print("inside test")

# fun(False) # comment if not in IDE mode

### comment following section if in IDE mode
if __name__ == "__main__":
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument("-a")

    args = argparser.parse_args()

    fun(args.a)
```

If I run the code above in a command line by calling `python basic_test.py -a False` I get the following strange (in my opinion) outputs:

```
arg1 value right before test:  False
inside test
```

So somehow the `arg1` is `False` at one line, yet `True` at the very next line, since the `if` section is entered? Why is it happening?

Moreover, if I comment the 'main' section, and uncomment the line `fun(False)`, and run that code into an IDE (Spyder in my case), it runs as I would expect it, with the following output:

```
arg1 value right before test:  False
```

So it indeed does not go into the `if` part.

I am running Python 3.7.6 on Windows if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`False` you're getting from argparse is string, unlike your synthetic check, where it's actual boolean.

Argparse has no implicit parsing for boolean literals, so apart from parsing them by hand, best way to go is to use `action='store_false'` and pass argument as a flag

Comment: I see, what should I modify to overcome this? Change `fun`, or change the `add_argument`, or both, or something else?

Comment: It also boils down I feel as how to pass a Boolean from command line?

Comment: Answering myself: it seems that doing`argparser.add_argument("--a", action='store_false')` works in that if you write`python basic_test.py --a` then it behaves as `False`, and if you ommit `--a` as in `python basic_test.py`, then it behaves as `True`.

Comment: Indeed, `store-*` option is what will work for flag-like case. I've updated unswer

Comment: Thanks, I would edit again, to add the extra quote missing at the end.